# 'require is not defined' in eclipse orion

Tags: node.js, eclipse-orion

I use eclipse orion with node.js together, but when using 'require' in the code below, eclipse orion complain that 'require is not defined', but the code execute just fine with node.

```
var sys = require("sys");
sys.puts("Hello World");
```

How is it possible to switch of the error message?

Comment: require is present in node itself. Orion must support Node.js for that. [Helpful link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Orion/Getting_Started_with_Orion_node#Developing_a_node.js_application)

Comment: How do you use eclipse orion?
via orionhub account?
local orion server?
local orionode installation?

Comment: Check this: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/12159/how-to-make-validation-in-orion-aware-of-the-node-js-runtime.html they comment couple of solutions although ugly from my point of view.